# oracle show error RMAN on replication

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

When I started run this RMAN script

```
run {
    allocate channel prmy1 type disk;
    allocate channel prmy2 type disk;
    allocate channel prmy3 type disk;
    allocate channel prmy4 type disk;
    allocate auxiliary channel stby type disk;
    duplicate target database for standby from active database
    spfile
        parameter_value_convert 'ARPISDEV','ARPISDEVSTBY'
        set db_unique_name='ARPISDEVSTBY'
        set db_file_name_convert='/ARPISDEV/','/ARPISDEVSTBY/'
        set log_file_name_convert='/ARPISDEV/','/ARPISDEVSTBY/'
        set control_files='/opt/oradata/ARPISDEVSTBY/control01.ctl'
        set log_archive_max_processes='5'
        set fal_client='ARPISDEVSTBY'
        set fal_server='ARPISDEV'
        set standby_file_management='AUTO'
        set log_archive_config='dg_config=(ARPISDEV,ARPISDEVSTBY)'
        set log_archive_dest_2='service=orcl ASYNC valid_for=(ONLINE_LOGFILE,PRIMARY_ROLE) db_unique_name=ARPISDEV'
     ;
     }
```

its returned me this errors

> `Starting backup at 11-APR-18 channel prmy1: starting datafile copy
>   input datafile file number=00010
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_data05.dbf channel prmy2: starting
>   datafile copy input datafile file number=00011
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_data04.dbf channel prmy3: starting
>   datafile copy input datafile file number=00012
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_data03.dbf channel prmy4: starting
>   datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00013
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_data02.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy1: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00014
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_data01.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy2 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy2: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00015
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_prod03.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy3: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00016
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_prod02.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy4 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy4: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00017
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_prod01.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy1: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00019
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_indx01.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy2 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy2: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00018
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/ar_work01.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy3: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00001
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/system01.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy1: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00002
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/sysaux01.dbf RMAN-03009: failure of backup
>   command on prmy2 channel at 04/11/2018 02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle
>   error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server continuing other job
>   steps, job failed will not be re-run channel prmy2: starting datafile
>   copy
>
> input datafile file number=00005 name=/redo/logs/redo05.log
>   RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy4 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
>   channel prmy4: starting datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00006 name=/redo/logs/redo04.log
>   RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
>   channel prmy1: starting datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00007 name=/redo/logs/redo03.log
>   RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
>   channel prmy3: starting datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00008 name=/redo/logs/redo02.log output
>   file name=/redo/logs/redo05.log tag=TAG20180411T023622 channel prmy2:
>   datafile copy complete, elapsed time: 00:00:03 channel prmy2: starting
>   datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00009 name=/redo/logs/redo01.log output
>   file name=/redo/logs/redo03.log tag=TAG20180411T023622 channel prmy1:
>   datafile copy complete, elapsed time: 00:00:04 channel prmy1: starting
>   datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00003
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/undotbs01.dbf output file
>   name=/redo/logs/redo02.log tag=TAG20180411T023622 channel prmy3:
>   datafile copy complete, elapsed time: 00:00:04 channel prmy3: starting
>   datafile copy
>
> input datafile file number=00004
>   name=/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV/users01.dbf output file
>   name=/redo/logs/redo04.log tag=TAG20180411T023622 channel prmy4:
>   datafile copy complete, elapsed time: 00:00:04
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:28 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:29 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
>   output file name=/redo/logs/redo01.log tag=TAG20180411T023622 channel
>   prmy2: datafile copy complete, elapsed time: 00:00:03 released
>   channel: prmy1 released channel: prmy2 released channel: prmy3
>   released channel: prmy4 released channel: stby RMAN-00571:
>   =========================================================== RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS
>   =============== RMAN-00571: =========================================================== RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 04/11/2018 02:36:30
>   RMAN-03015: error occurred in stored script Memory Script
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy2 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy4 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy2 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy4 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy2 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:23 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:29 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:28 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy1 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server
>
> RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on prmy3 channel at 04/11/2018
>   02:36:24 ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
>   server`
>
> RMAN> **end-of-file**

please help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

There was former copy of the database files under the same location where the duplicate is restoring. Files with the same name as well.

The datafiles under `/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV` on the standby already exist from previous database in this case.

> Delete the old datafiles from previous database under the location
>   `/opt/oradata/ARPISDEV` where you trying to restore the database.